# What should I do with my HTTP property in Google Console after I forced all my traffic to HTTPS with 301 redirection?

Tags: seo, google-search, https

A few months ago, I've switched all my traffic from HTTP to HTTPS. And then I have two properties in Google Search Console.

I would like the `http` site be replaced by `https` site totally. Can I do something in the Search Console? Like turn a preference settings saying "Please ignore the http search results and show only https search results".

Comment: You should have 4 properties in Google WMT, see linked question and answers.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. Yes, 4. https/http and www/ /o